# What did The Doctor mean with "Pond, bring the fish"?

Tags: doctor-who

In season 6, 'The God Complex' The Doctor, Amy and Rita are running after the 'bad guy',

> DOCTOR: Stay back!
>
> (The Minotaur smashes a glass door and knocks Rory down.)
>
> DOCTOR: Pond, bring the fish.
>
> AMY: What, the fish? Oh, the fish.

What does he mean? This has been bothering me for a while now.
Maybe I just don't get the joke, because I don't speak English as my first language..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm pretty sure The Doctor is talking about an actual goldfish in a fishbowl that he finds in the hotel. When the Doctor traps the Minotaur in the one of the rooms, you can see several shots of the fishbowl with a goldfish swimming around in it. Presumably, the fish is real, and The Doctor is trying to save the fish along with everyone else. (I think the fish gets eaten later, unfortunately.)

There's no deeper meaning or significance to his request to Amy. There's a literal fish and he wants Amy to grab it and run.

Comment: I know, that this isn't even remotely important, but the little things just get to me sometimes..

Comment: it's in the same room as that water fountain, but it's just a small fishbowl.

Comment: Ok, ty. I just get stuck with these things.. Like, why does The Doctor sprinkle pepper to Graigs shoulders in the next episode.. But that's just The Doctor, i suppose..

Comment: There is a little pun there though. Fish often live in ponds, and asking a "pond" to get a fish, taken out of context, sounds rather ridiculous.